# In-Memory OLTP backup and restore

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016, in-memory-database

I have one memory optimized filegroup with one container but there's no object in it. So what is the backup and restoration process for this and how much space and time it will take in comparison with normal database(disk based).
And is it possible to restore memory optimized database backup(no object in memory optimized form) to non memory optimized database?

There's a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn553123.aspx) for this but it didn't tell me the script and empty momory optimized files.

Answer (score 0):

If your memory optimized table is 'Schema and data' then obviously it can be backed up and restore it. But not for 'Schema' only

```
WITH  
    (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON,  
    DURABILITY = SCHEMA_AND_DATA);
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing few test I've found that the database backup is done by normal script

```
BACKUP DATABASE <db name>
TO DISK = 'disk location.bak'
WITH COMPRESSION
```

And restoration is also the same but once you replace(WITH REPLACE) disk based database with memory optimized database backup, then restored database will be also memory optimized database. And we don't need to mention memory optimized filegroup specification while restore script.

But there's an issue which I've found that I am not able to change the path of the file of memory optimized filegroup.